# How to solve: Why is coreData(NSFetchedResultsController) sorting differently in iOS5 and iOS4

Tags: sorting, ios5, core-data, ios4, nsfetchedresultscontroller

i have a tableview which is populated with NSFetchedResultsController.
On `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`i am updating the current `row`. The sorting here should not change. The difference in the selected row is, that i mark it as read. No title changes or something.

In iOS4 the row gets updated and still leave on his current place, it does not move to the end of section. Thats the right way.

in iOS5 the row gets also updated but it moves to the end of the Section. I want to prevent that. How can i do that? And why is that happening?

See my code:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
if (__fetchedResultsController != nil)
{
    return __fetchedResultsController;
}


NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"EntitySetsCardsInbox" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSPredicate *inboxPred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"archived == 0 AND cardId != 0"];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:inboxPred];


if (sortString == nil) {
    //sortString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"sortingOrder"];
    sortString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"colorOrder"];
    sortAsc = NO;
}


if ([sortString isEqualToString:@"cardTitle"]) {
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor2 = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:sortString ascending:sortAsc selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] autorelease];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor2, nil] autorelease];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    XLog(@"sortDescriptors: %@", sortDescriptors);
} else {
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor2 = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:sortString ascending:sortAsc] autorelease];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor2, nil] autorelease];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    XLog(@"sortDescriptors: %@", sortDescriptors);
}


NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    [...]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think your sortdescriptor is changing when you updating your rows. add one more sortdescriptor to fix the list with it and check it again. in my case i have a very similar issue and it solved my problem. maybe yours, too.